# Exe file wont run

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I just ended up building my final project, so wanted to convert it from **.py** to **.exe**, after watching the different tutorial and followed one which used **cx_Freeze** but still after creating the **.exe** it doesn't run.

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name="RMS", version="0.1", description="Your resturant made easy", executables=[Executable(r"C:\Data\Final Project.py")])
```

Comment: you say it doesn't run, what does happen? error messages?

Comment: Well what errors are you getting?  We can't guess. If your not sure run the exe from command  prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm guessing that it's the tkinter runtimes that are missing (that's what it usually is).  You need to use the `include_files` argument to include them like this:

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name="RMS", version="0.1", options = {"include_files": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\DLLs\tk86t.dll", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\DLLs\tcl86t.dll"}, executables=[Executable(r"C:\Data\Final Project.py")])
```

Also remember to use `\\` not `\`.  You can also use `/` instead if you want.  A very short paragraph is mentioned on the [`include_files` argument here](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html).